# Как работают java.util.prefs.Preferences в Java?

Tags: java

Наткнулся на документацию метода *flush()*, которая гласит, что метод нужен для форсирования изменений в ноде. Разве при записи в Preferences изменения сами по себе не моментально применяются? Имеется ввиду запись через

- `preferences.node(String name)`- создание ноды
- `preferences.put(String key, String value)` - добавление ключа-значения в ноду
- `Preferences.importPreferences(InputStream is)` - импорт преференсов из потока (файлового, например)

Исходники Java лично мне не совсем понятны в вопросе того, как работает класс Preferences. Может кто объяснить, в каких случаях нужно применять `preferences.flush()` и что будет, если этого не делать?

Comment: Посмотрите наследника, FileSystemPreferences. Там первыми же строками написано что SYNC_INTERVAL по умолчанию раз в 30 секунд, минимально - раз в секунду.

Comment: В документации пишут что когда выполнен flush() можно быть уверенным что записи надежно записаны, если не вызвав и убить процесс, то можно потерять то что еще не записано в хранилище, периодичность синхронизации имплементации выбирают самостоятельно.

Comment: @zRrr пожалуйста! Как смог. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации пишут, что [flush()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#flush()) при вызове должен сохранить все изменения в хранилище. Иными словами после его успешного завершения данные пользователь может быть уверен в том, что данные не потеряются. Если же не вызывав этот метод убить процесс JVM, можно потерять то, что еще не записано. Имплементации этого абстрактного класса вольны сами выбирать частоту вызова этого метода, т.е. не обязаны ждать пока пользователь его вызовет.

К примеру если посмотреть имплементацию FileSystemPreferences, в первых строках можно видеть:

```
/**
 * Sync interval in seconds.
 */
private static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = Math.max(1,
    Integer.parseInt(
        AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction(
                "java.util.prefs.syncInterval", "30"))));
```

Интервал синхронизации по умоланию  - 30 секунд, но не меньше 1 секунды.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вопрос вдогонку: если я записываю (`importPreferences(InputStream)`), а потом сразу же считываю данные из Preferences (`exportSubtree(OutputStream)`), может ли быть такое, что не все даные окажутся в считывающем потоке?

Comment: Если сразу же после, в том же потоке - не должны. Если пытаетесь это делать из другого потока - можете. importPreferences вызвает ImportSubtree, который синхронизируется по узлам. Смотрите javadoc: exportSubtree : "... If the preferences or nodes in the subtree rooted at this node are modified concurrently with an invocation of this method  ...  If the preferences or nodes in the subtree rooted at this node are modified concurrently with an invocation of this method"